# Cannot archive release version of my IOS Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

I'm currently trying to archive a release version of my IOS xamarin project so I can upload it to the app store connect for submission. The project builds fine in debug and now runs in release after setting 'GenerateSerializationAssembly' to 'Off' but when I go to archive the project I get error below:

```
2>SGEN : error : Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.9, Cultureneutral, PublicKeyToken-7cecs5d7bea7798e’ or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: @xB013141A)
```

Comment: Which the Linker behavior you select ?`Don't Link` or `Link sdk only` ?

Comment: Link Framework SDKs Only

Comment: Switch to `Don't Link` , try again .

Comment: Still get the error, cheers though

Comment: Are you using web service ? Check the similar case: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5458/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mscorlib-version-2-0-5-0-culture-neutral-publickeytoken-7cec85d7

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2019 and I already had signed the assembly.

I fixed it by this way: Right click on the project which causes the issue -> "Properties" -> "Build" -> Change the value of the "Platform target" field.

I had to change it from Any CPU to x86 but I guess that in function of the project and the library which is failing, you should change its value to x64.